# How to find the method name inside of itself (Javascript / Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, methods

How do I retrieve the name of a **method** from within itself? As well as the **method** that called it?

I am talking **methods** not functions.

It is possible with functions, by using `arguments.callee.name` and `arguments.callee.caller.name`.

But on class methods accessing these produce an error: `Uncaught TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them`

Is there a way similar to functions for methods?

```js
/* this fails with an error
Uncaught TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
*/

class xyz {

  constructor() {
    // this works
    console.log(this.constructor.name)
  }

  method1(val) {
    // this fails
    console.log(arguments.callee.name)
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name)
    this.method2(val)
  }

  method2(val) {
    // this also fails
    console.log(arguments.callee.name)
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name)
  }
}

let XYZ = new xyz()
XYZ.method1('some value')
XYZ.method2('another value')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need this information? What's the use case? Are you sure this isn't an XY problem? In 99% of cases there isn't a good reason why your method needs to know what it's called.

Comment: No, arguments.callee.name does not work in class methods and produces an error.

Comment: methods are functions. But  because the use of `callee` is deprecated, the newer `class` syntax does not even allow them: they implicitly enforce strict mode rules. If you really really want this, then move to the old constructor syntax with its assignments of methods to the `prototype` object. But don't... (it's deprecated).

Comment: One way is to inspect the stack. You can get the stacktrace from an Error object, though I'm not sure why you would want to do something like that.

Comment: @esqew this question was about methods, not functions. The "duplicate" post does not solve this question. As demonstrated in the above code, the solution for functions produces errors for methods.

Comment: Quoted from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee): *Warning: The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of `arguments.callee()` in strict mode. Avoid using `arguments.callee()` by either giving function expressions a name or use a function declaration where a function must call itself.*

Comment: @trincot, ouch! That is a real gotcha. Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I want this for error handling. The error handler can look up where the error thrown, without the method name having to be passed to it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 this does the trick, but I was hoping for something simpler

error.stack.split('\n')[1].split('at ')[1].split(' ')[0]